# Lightning Components: How to get sforce.one on any Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

My use case is a rewrite of the Standard Lightning Component "Visualforce" which lets you embed a Visualforce page on a Flexipage.

The reason for this rewrite is, that the Standard "Visualforce" component is simply not powerful enough, i.e. setting a fixed height in pixel (with a maximum of 600) is simple unacceptable for my use cases.

Now it's pretty simple to use an `<iframe>` in a Custom Lightning Component. The only thing missing then in the embedded VF Page is `sforce.one` - which is needed for several patterns.

How to get `force.one` on any Visualforce page?

Comment: If you are inside the SF1 container then you will get the sforce.one automatically .Any issue ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava : No, you won't get it automatically. You get that baby only, if you use the Standard "Visualforce" Lightning component - with all it's weaknesses. Using your own iframe instead, you'll loose it.

Answer (score 9):

One method I found is to add the URL parameter `isdtp=p1` at the end of the iframes `src` attribute. Having `isdtp=p1` in the URL of any Visualforce page seems to enforce the presence of `sforce.one`.

I noticed, that the Standard "Visualforce" Component also adds `sfdcIFrameHost=web` and `sfdcIFrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2FYOUR_DOMAIN.lightning.force.com` (YOUR_DOMAIN replaced with yours of course)

At this point I haven't reverse engineered what exactly they do, but I think it's a good idea to provide them both. At least they seem to do no harm to the VF-page. In case I'll find out more details, I'll extend this answer.

Comment: Just beware if you try to use private APIs like this, things will break in future releases. There is no contract or public commitment to keep this behavior.

Comment: @RobertSussland : agreed, but how to do it now the right way, if the Standard Visualforce Component is really not good enough for our current use-cases? Do you see any viable alternative other than to provide isdtp=p1 to an iframe to improve that today with the given public APIs?

Comment: There is not a secure way to do this right now, however I believe this use case is being addressed right now. In the mean time, please hold off on trying to hack a solution.